# How to create thick cone in WPF using HelixToolkit or other?

Tags: wpf, 3d

how can I create a thick cone using the Helixtoolkit library (I prefer Helix but custom code is fine as well), if I use the MeshBuilder.AddCone method without cap, it is too thin that in some angle, the cone disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the disappear problem by setting BackMaterial properties. It is not a thick cone yet but solve my problem.